# Play Again Button Tkinter Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I made the game hangman inside tkinter with a friend of mine, and we are nearly finished but we'd like to add a button that says play again and replays the game, but we can't figure out the correct way of doing it. My original idea was to create a play again button to close out the current window, open up a new one with the same basis, and play the game again, but whenever it comes to the "Easy" "Medium" and "Hard" buttons, they don't do anything. I'd prefer solutions that don't include using other modules. Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to include the code!!! I'm dumb, sorry!

```
    from tkinter import *

import random as r

import time as tm

#Hang Man


class menu:

    def __init__(self):

        self.game = Tk()

        self.game.geometry('600x600+50+50')

        self.game.title("Hang Man")

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.game,height=400,width=800,bg='light goldenrod yellow')  

        self.canvas.delete(ALL)

        self.canvas.create_line(100,50,100,500,tags="Line") #Vertical

        self.canvas.create_line(20,500,80,500,tags="Line") #Lower Horizontal

        self.canvas.create_line(100,50,150,50,tags="Line") #Horizontal Line

        self.canvas.pack() 

        self.play = Button(self.game,text="Play",command=self.playbt)

        self.play.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.game.mainloop() # Create an event loop

    def playagain(self):

        self.game.destroy()

        self.__init__()

    def playbt(self):

      self.difs()



    def difs(self):

        self.play.destroy()

        self.easy = Button(self.game,text="Easy",command=self.easy)

        self.medium = Button(self.game,text="Medium",command=self.medium)

        self.hard = Button(self.game,text="Hard",command=self.hard)



        self.easy.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.medium.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.hard.pack(side=BOTTOM)



    def easy(self):

        ewords = r.choice(["TABLE","CHAIR","DESK","PHONE","LIGHT","MAN"])

        self.playP(ewords.lower())

    def medium(self):

        mwords = r.choice(["PYTHON","LAPTOP","JACKET","VIDEO","MODULE","LIBRARY"])

        self.playP(mwords.lower())

    def hard(self):

        hwords = r.choice(["PROGRAM","TOLEDO","UNIVERSITY","ENGINEER","FOOTBALL","LANGUAGE"])

        self.playP(hwords.lower())



    def playP(self,words):

        self.lwords = words

        for i in range(0, len(self.lwords)):

            self.canvas.create_text(300+20*i,310,text="_",font="Times 16",tags="text")

        self.hm = 0

        self.easy.destroy()

        self.medium.destroy()

        self.hard.destroy()

        self.myscore = int(0)



        self.te = StringVar() #Text Entry TextVariable

        self.teb = Entry(self.game, textvariable = self.te) #Text Entry Box

        self.tebt = Button(self.game,text="Submit", command = self.checkAnswer)

        self.teb.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.tebt.pack(side=BOTTOM)





    def checkAnswer(self):

        temp= self.te.get()

        score=0 #trial set for each try

        score1=0

        x1=300


        for i in range(0,len(self.lwords)):



            if temp==self.lwords[i]:

                self.canvas.create_text(x1+20*i,300,text=self.lwords[i],font="Times 16",tags="text")

                score1+=1

                self.myscore += 1


            if self.myscore == len(self.lwords):

                self.win()


        if not (score1 > score):

           self.draw()

           score=0 

           score1



    def win(self):

        self.canvas.delete(ALL)

        self.canvas.after(100)

        self.teb.destroy()

        self.tebt.destroy()

        self.canvas.create_text(400,200,text = 'YOU WIN!!',font='Times 36')

        self.pa = Button(self.game,text="Play Again?",command=self.playagain)

        self.pa.pack(side=BOTTOM)



    def draw(self):

        self.hm += 1

        if self.hm == 1:

          self.canvas.create_oval(125,50,175,100, tags = "Line") #Head

        elif self.hm == 2:

          self.canvas.create_line(150,100,150,150, tags = "Line") #Body

        elif self.hm == 3:

          self.canvas.create_line(150,125,125,100, tags = "Line") #Left Arm

        elif self.hm == 4:

          self.canvas.create_line(150, 125, 175, 100, tags = "Line") #Right Arm

        elif self.hm == 5:

          self.canvas.create_line(150,150,125,175, tags = "Line") #Left Leg

        elif self.hm == 6:

          self.canvas.create_line(150,150,175,175, tags = "Line") #Right Leg

          self.canvas.update()

          self.canvas.after(100)

          self.canvas.delete(ALL)

          self.canvas.create_text(200,200,text="HANG MAN!!",font="Times 36")

          self.tebt.destroy()

          self.teb.destroy()

          self.pa = Button(self.game,text="Play Again?",command=self.playagain)

          self.pa.pack(side=BOTTOM)







menu()
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Please try to condense it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry bout that Bryan, I'm still kind of new here even though I made my account a while ago Lol I 'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do agree with Novel that you should recreate the window instead of the Tkinter instance however  I wanted to provide a simple solution that goes along with your original idea.

The simplest answer is to change

This:

```
def playagain(self):
    self.game.destroy()
    self.__init__()
```

to:

```
def playagain(self):
    self.game.destroy()
    menu()
```

This will end the current Tkinter instance and start a new one by calling on the "menu" class again.

Comment: If you do that you need to explicitly set the master for all the Tkinter widgets including variables and images or you'll get strange bugs.

Comment: @Novel It operates just fine for me. I ran through it several times with no bugs. And the main tkinter instance is created within the class itself so if the class is called on it just creates a new instance of the app. Should not cause any strange bugs.

Comment: I don't think OP uses any variables or images. I was just providing a warning if they do in the future.

Comment: @Novel. Humm. I would be interested to know exactly why what you say is an issue. Just looking at the code I do not see anything that could cause strange bugs using the method I posted. I am no expert but its just not something that stands out to me.

Comment: @Novel when you say `explicitly set the master for all the Tkinter widgets including variables and images` I am not sure I follow. Images and variables do not usually reference the master directly that I know of.

Comment: Not usually, no. Because they default to the first one created. But if you use more than one `Tk()` then you have to explicitly provide the correct one. [I made you an example](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/a354fef60905db5a781de309a45c8740).

Comment: Besides, this is looping via recursion and is a textbook memory leak.

Comment: @Novel, I think I see what you are saying however the instance of Tk() is actually being destroyed before the new one is created. This should prevent any issues like you have described.

Comment: I feel dumb cause not only is that obvious, but I tried it and it didn't work for me lol. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Ok, as long as you destroy() before the next Tk().

Answer (score 1):

No, don't try to remake the window. Remake the widgets in the window, the same way you made them at the beginning. You clearly know how to clear the canvas and buttons. Do that and then redo the initialization step. To make it neater, make a function that you call both at boot and at playagain.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.game = Tk()
    self.game.geometry('600x600+50+50')
    self.game.title("Hang Man")
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.game,height=400,width=800,bg='light goldenrod yellow')
    self.canvas.delete(ALL)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.init_ui()
    self.game.mainloop() # Create an event loop

def playagain(self):
    self.canvas.delete('ALL') # clear the canvas
    self.init_ui()

def init_ui(self):
    self.canvas.create_line(100,50,100,500,tags="Line") #Vertical
    self.canvas.create_line(20,500,80,500,tags="Line") #Lower Horizontal
    self.canvas.create_line(100,50,150,50,tags="Line") #Horizontal Line
    self.play = Button(self.game,text="Play",command=self.playbt)
    self.play.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Also, what's with the double line spacing? Holy cow that's annoying.

Comment: Lol sorry about the double spacing, someone else did it that way, and this solution didn't work it just gave me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

who are using OS module can refer my code , see use global variable if u want to play next song , why i posted it , i solved it by myself , so i am happy
so who are using os module can refer it

```
from tkinter import *
import os


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("music player ")
Label(root, text="MUSIC PLAYER").pack()
i=0

def prev():
   pass
def paly():
    music_dir = 'D:\songs'
    songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
    print(songs)
    os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))
def nxt():
    global i
    music_dir = 'D:\songs'
    songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
    print(songs)
    os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[i]))
    i=i+1
f1=Frame(root).pack()
Button(f1,text="prev",command=prev).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30)
Button(f1,text="play/pause",command=paly).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30)
Button(f1,text="next",command=nxt).pack(side=LEFT,padx=30)


root.mainloop()
```